# Hotkeys do not work when switching to Russian

Tags: keyboard

Many programs stop replying to the letter keys on the keyboard when switching to the Russian layout.
For example, a blender.
Both Inkscape and Gimp have problems.
In Ubuntu, POP! OS, Manjaro, Open Suse, no problem.

---

This acute problem is still unresolved.
Please pay attention of the developers.

Comment: Do you mean keyboard shortcuts (i.e. CTRL+C) or the letter keys (normal typing)?

Comment: Yes! you got it right!

Comment: You got a solution?

Answer (score 1):

This should be fixed by entering the following commands to enable the hotkeys for the Russian keyboard layout:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attent/java-non-latin-shortcuts

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

restart unity-setting-daemon
```

After then you should restart your computer and check whether the hotkeys are working correctly.

Comment: Not working/
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~attent/ubuntu/java-non-latin-shortcuts'.
ERROR: '~attent' user or team does not exist

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:attente/java-non-latin-shortcuts 
Error: retrieving gpg key timed out.

Comment: ppa:attent/java-non-latin-shortcuts
not supported ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Concerning non-working keyboard shortcuts for Russian keyboard layout:
I have reported this issue to blender developers (see [here](https://developer.blender.org/T64197)). Based on their answer, this might be OS-specific (i.e. not Linux-specific, but elementary OS-specific) issue, because Russian shortcuts seem to work fine in blender on Ubuntu 18.04.

**@moderator** I'd like to report this issue as a bug. Which channel would you suggest as appropriate for this kind of issue?

Comment: I still don't know if there's a solution to the problem.

Comment: @Hasan That's not the right repo in this case. That repo contains the code for the keyboard settings panels, which have nothing to do with keyboard usage in general.

Comment: @PeterUithoven I am sorry for the mistake. Can you please help me by telling which one is the right one or please post the right one, i am deleting my comment. Thank you very much for pointing that out.

Comment: @Hasan I'd open it in the catch all "OS" repo, because it's quite unclear where this issue comes from.